# Swift 4 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo save image

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to use my camera like so:

```
@objc func toggle() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

            //Define UIImagePickerController variable

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

            //Assign the delegate

            imagePicker.delegate = self

            //Set image picker source type

            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

            //Allow Photo Editing

            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

            //Present camera

            UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to capture the image taken using the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, I got this example online:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! NSURL
        let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
        let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
        let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
        let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

        do
        {
            try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
        }
        catch
        {
            // Catch exception here and act accordingly
        }

        UIApplication.topViewController()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
```

But I changed UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL to UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage as UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is nil. but after I change that I get this fatal error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIImage' (0x1b6b02b58) to 'NSURL'

How do I save the image take from the camera? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your code as following this will give you image.

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage return image not NSURL

Write following code to get image url in iOS 11. From iOS 11 UIImagePickerControllerImageURL is available, earlier there are UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL key to get image url.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
        print(imageURL)
    }
} else {
    if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
        print(imageUrl)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Right, but how do I get the URL of UIImage?

Comment: @user979331, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: `UIImagePickerControllerImageURL` is not a key in info though

Comment: If you are using earlier than iOS 11 than you need to use UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL key. See final edited answer.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is also not a key :(

Comment: Is there something on info.plist I have to add?

Comment: If you have't  added permission key to access photo library, then you required it.

Comment: I have Privacy - Camera Usage Description in my info.plist

Comment: Yes, then it is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167111/discussion-between-paul-marshal-and-user979331).

Comment: As of Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10) the key has changed to `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` as in `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any])`. You can then get the image with `info[.originalImage] as? UIImage`

Answer (score 3):

The one who are searching for complete method to implement for **Swift 4.2+**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    imgPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This will return you the `original image` according to new syntax

For **Image URL** and **Media URL**, Use the respective

```
let imgURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL]
let mediaURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]
```

Comment: This is for Swift 4.2+.